# NSArray with online content

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I'm working on an app to show a list of videos (tableView) and I would like to be able to modify the list without making a new update of the app everytime I change one thing.

I've heared about JSon or XML but I would be sure if it's the best and easier way for me to achieve this. I don't have a big list, 10 object max.

Thank's a lot,

Nicolas

Comment: JSON. most definitly, unless you have a really complex structure.

Comment: You should have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536893/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-xml-and-json) if you didn't already.

Comment: @NicolasWilhem You should post a separate question if you have more questions, not edit your old one. Would you revert your change and post a new question?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'll make it directly. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON is easy to parse and handle. You should go with JSON without thinking too much. Go Ahead !

Comment: Thank's Rajan. Do you know a good and clear tutorial? I saw some but it was always only for twitter or youtube JSon. I would like to do my own JSon file. Thanks again.

Comment: @NicolasWilhem Check this out : http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 and don't write 'JSon' its JSON :)

Comment: Thanks! It's not "J" son's?? ;-)